# Prevent Comments in Code Block

Tags: support, code-formatting

When I create a code block, 2 dashes is interpreted as a comment. How do I prevent this?

For example, the "--version" text is shown in a lighter color, as if it's a comment. But it should be the same shade as the rest of the line, as it's part of the command.

```
./mysql --version
```

Comment: Use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to have everything boring .... see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100 it helps if you can share which tags are used on the question you posted that example.

Comment: @rene is this going to eliminate all colors ? that's not what is asked here...

Comment: @AntoinePelletier yes, beyond that it is probably a google prettify bug, not something that is going to be fixed by SE. You could force any of the other highlighters I linked to and see if any of those works better

Comment: Yes, totally agree with your explanation. So the reel answer is : it's going to stay as it is